# What does "val XXX = Class { ... " mean in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, lambda, anonymous-function

In Kotlin, what does this syntax mean ?

```
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val examplesAdapter =  HomeOptionsAdapter {
        val fragment = it.createView()
        ...
    }
```

> https://github.com/kizitonwose/CalendarView/blob/6be23be1f721fe2e08e5f2e2e7f29ad0b519c327/sample/src/main/java/com/kizitonwose/calendarviewsample/HomeActivity.kt#L15

I just thought Anonymous function or Lambdas ...

Comment: It should be the onclick lambda take a look at [HomeOptionsAdapter](https://github.com/kizitonwose/CalendarView/blob/6be23be1f721fe2e08e5f2e2e7f29ad0b519c327/sample/src/main/java/com/kizitonwose/calendarviewsample/HomeOptionsAdapter.kt) definition.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. 
That means this ```{val fragment = it.createView()...}``` part is HomeOptionsAdapter's constructor?

Comment: But, it's not wrapped by `()`. Are there anything Abbreviations ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I you check the `HomeOptionsAdapter` you'll see in the constructor this

```
class HomeOptionsAdapter(val onClick: (ExampleItem) -> Unit)
```

so it takes an onClick listener, a function that takes a `ExampleItem` as input and returns `Unit`. This is a Kotlin language feature, you can place a lambda outside the `()` if it's the last parameter. These are equivalent:

```
val examplesAdapter =  HomeOptionsAdapter({
    val fragment = it.createView()
    ...
})

val examplesAdapter =  HomeOptionsAdapter {
    val fragment = it.createView()
    ...
}
```

Comment: In other words, it's a [trailing lambda](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#passing-a-lambda-to-the-last-parameter). I didn't realize they could be used with constructors.